# segue not passing data over

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

im still having problems with my segue
i have at the moment

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Check that a new transition has been requested to the DetailViewController and prepares for it
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WeddingDetail"]){

    // Capture the object (e.g. exam) the user has selected from the list
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Set destination view controller to DetailViewController to avoid the NavigationViewController in the middle (if you have it embedded into a navigation controller, if not ignore that part)
    UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
    DMKWeddingDetailViewController *detailViewController = (DMKWeddingDetailViewController *) nav.nextResponder;
    detailViewController.exam = object;
    NSLog(@"object details: %@",object);
}
}
```

i was hoping that exam would hold the data but it isnt the data is held in object. but not sure how to pass object over to detail view controller.

in my detailview controller i have a list if textlabels

```
self.name.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"name"];
```

but they are not populating

Comment: Are you sure that `[segue destinationViewController]` is a `UINavigationController` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case that the destination ViewController is a UINavigationController, I think the problem is in

```
DMKWeddingDetailViewController *detailViewController = (DMKWeddingDetailViewController *) nav.nextResponder;
```

you should use this instead

```
DMKWeddingDetailViewController *detailViewController = (DMKWeddingDetailViewController *) [nav topViewController];
```

and if the destination is your target ViewController you should use

```
DMKWeddingDetailViewController *detailViewController = (DMKWeddingDetailViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
```